# Warning with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am implementeinbg MPMoviePlayerController, I am using this method (presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated) to present when i am

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayerController.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;


[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
```

But i am getting warning incompatible type when i am presenting i am passing the required argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to present [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of [MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html) that is why the warning.

Also keep in mind that there is no `controlStyle` property for `MPMoviePlayerViewController`

So use like:

```
- (void)showMedia
{
   MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerView.moviePlayer];

   [moviePlayerView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
   moviePlayerView.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
   [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not presenting a View Controller but a MPMoviePlayerController. That is a different object. If you want to present the movie player controller in a view controller go and try to use MPMoviePlayerViewController.